# How to free up Bokeh server after disconnecting from app (getting error: port 5006 is already in use)

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm on day 1 of using Bokeh, and I'm trying to understand how the server works. First, I ran one of the example apps with

```
bokeh serve --show main.py
```

And I saw this info:

[image]

So then I saw there were no other unused sessions available, so I wasn't entirely surprised when I tried to run another app in parallel (launched from another window with the same command) and it failed:

[image]

So then I thought if I closed the app window I would be able to run a different app, and I noticed the server did register that I closed the web browser:

[image]

However I am still getting this error:

```
port 5006 is already in use
```

I went through the docs, and I apologize if I am missing something, but my two questions are

1. How can I get the server to serve more than one app in parallel with different browser tabs?
2. How an I reset the server when I close the browser window so that even if only one client can be served at a time, the server knows that a browser has been closed and another client should be accepted?

Thanks for suggestions and links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start multiple apps with a single invocation of the `bokeh` command:

```
bokeh serve --show app1.py, app2/ app3.py
```

Or you can run different apps on different ports explicitly:

```
bokeh serve --show --port 5001 app1.py
bokeh serve --show --port 5002 app2.py
```

Comment: Command line options are documented here: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/cli.html#module-bokeh.command.subcommands.serve

Comment: This is a good workaround for the problem, however it doen't answer the question how to close port 5006. The other answer does (at least under linux)

Answer (score 2):

If there is ever a need to use port 5006 (for whatever reason). For linux this is the solution:
Get the process ID from

```
netstat -tupln
```

Note down the PID from the list, and the run the following command

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Now you should be able to use the default port again!